# Trickle FTP connection

Tags: bash, ftp, trickle

I have a script for backing up my data. The last line is:

```
echo "$FTPConnectstring
$FTPCommands
bye" | ftp -ivn
```

It works great, but I wish I could 'trickle' this (i.e. limit upload bandwidth usage).
I tried many command lines like these:

```
echo "$FTPConnectstring
$FTPCommands
bye" | ftp -ivn | trickle -s -u 4096
```

but ftp transfer seems to execute with no BW usage limit 
I also tried something like this

```
FinalCommand=$(echo -e "$FTPConnectstring\n$FTPCommands\nbye")
trickle -s -u 4096 ftp -ivn ${FinalCommand}
```

but this one doesn't connect ftp correctly...

Any help appreciated !!

Comment: The correct syntax would be something like `echo -e "$FTPConnectstring\n$FTPCommands\nbye" | trickle -s -u 4096 ftp -ivn` but if `ftp` is statically linked, this probably doesn't do what you had hoped.

Comment: thx for your comment. Should I understand that what I'm trying to achieve is not possible ?

Comment: If it doesn't work, try using a different FTP client like `ncftp` which should also be easier to script. Maybe experiment with omitting the `-s` option if you have the daemon running.

Comment: FYI : ldd $(which ftp) | grep libc.so returns libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6... as expected for working with trickle. I tried your suggestion and the result is the same, no BW limit applied...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first attempt, you only `trickle` the standard output from `ftp` (depending on the implementation, probably just the progress messages, if even that). In your second attempt, you have a syntax error; the argument to `ftp` should be a host name, not a command sequence. Try this instead:

```
echo -e "$FTPConnectstring\n$FTPCommands\nbye" |
trickle -s -u 4096 ftp -ivn
```

If the `ftp` binary is statically linked, `trickle` can't override its socket-handling internals; but in that case, you can probably switch to a different FTP client such as `ncftp` which should also behave better with scripting.